# How to create backups of DVD software discs?

Tags: backup, software, dvd

I'd like to make some backups of my software DVDs that I can use to install the software again in case they are lost or get damaged. What's the best way to do this? Is it creating a `.cdr` disk image of the DVD using Disk Utility?

Note that some are multiple install DVDs i.e. a set of 9 or so DVDs.

Thanks,

Osu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, the best way to back them up is to create an image. You should create multiple images for multiple disks, otherwise the installer may look for data in another disk. You can save images for a set of disks in one folder to organise them.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me - so just creating multiple disk images and placing them in the same folder will sort out the 'please insert next DVD' prompt I'll get if installing from a disk image?

Comment: Yep. It will. Just start opening the other images as the installer asks for them.

Answer (score 2):

A good way to back up of software CD/DVD install media is to create a disk image for each disk you want to back up, then you can store those disks images on a backup hard-drives, etc. The '.cdr' format is essentially a [`.iso`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_image) which is the industry standard way of representing software disk images, so its a pretty good universal choice, that works on many platforms.

**To create a disk image for an optical disk using the Disk Utility Application:**

1. Open the Disk Utility Program
2. Insert the CD/DVD you want to create a disk image for.
3. Select the mounted CD/DVD disk under the "Super Drive" dive icon.
4. Click the Unmount button.
5. Select the the unmounted CD/DVD disk, by clicking once on it.
6. Select "File" menu > "New" > Disk Image from  "YourCD/DVD Disk"
7. Set where you want to save the disk image and select Image Format: "DVD/CD master" plus any other options you would like, and the press "Save"